Get Wikipedia page ID instead of Wikilink after reconciliation with Wikidata in Open Refine
I know how to download Wikipedia Sitelinks in Open Refine after reconciliation with Wikidata.
I use "Add column from reconciled column ... " and use "SPARQL: Senwiki" as property path for the English Wikipedia.
Is it possible, to get (instead of the site link) the Wikipedia page ID? The page is stable for later changes in the Wikipedia.
I know that there is an indirect way:
How to get Wikipedia page id from Wikidata id?
But is there a direct way with Open Refine?
Best regards and thanks in advance

I currently do not know a one step solution.
But if you already have the correct title of the Wikipedia page (using the "SPARQL: Semwiki" property as mentioned in the question), you can get the pageid from the Wikipedia API.
In OpenRefine use "Edit column" => "Add column by fetching URLs..." on the column with the correct page titles. As GREL expression use:
"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles="+escape(value, 'url')+"&format=json"

Please note that you obviously have to use the same language prefix as you used to retrieve the page titles (in your case en).
You will receive some JSON as output, that you can either try to parse or you can use a regular expression to transform the JSON content to a column containing only the pageids. For example use the following GREL expression in the "Edit cells" => "Transform..." dialog on the column with the JSON output from the Wikipedia API:
value.find(/(?<="pageid":)\s*\d+/)[0].trim()

Hope this helps and maybe there is an easier solution in the future.

Thank you, this approach worked for me. The only thing I needed to to in advance is: edit cells -> transform: replace(value, "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", " ") and edit cells -> common transformations -> trim leading and trailing whitespaces
